# Token in uri trimmed when trying to connect

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to socket.io hosted on our server and I'm getting the error message. When comparing two tokens (one provided in code, and other in the logs), token in the logs is shorter than one provided.

Code with token:

```swift
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
let token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijc1M2Y5YmZkMjRiMzBmODA0N2JjMmQ1YzY4MzYxZjc2YzM5NjBhNTdmZjhmNWU5YmJmY2Q0NTdjZTIxNTY1ZjYwNTk5YTczZWM4NTJjNmMxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiNzUzZjliZmQyNGIzMGY4MDQ3YmMyZDVjNjgzNjFmNzZjMzk2MGE1N2ZmOGY1ZTliYmZjZDQ1N2NlMjE1NjVmNjA1OTlhNzNlYzg1MmM2YzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODQ2MjAzNDYsIm5iZiI6MTU4NDYyMDM0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTg1OTE2MzQ2LCJzdWIiOiIzMCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.Dhsn0vm1B7W_6sfHPgUox6qO3hYEnsvMQC_sGCNnviWNL_U45sUkT2W_dijjk2Px6ugyib6x9OcSqHB_bnKAWFdopZY7KU21uxxLy-p-f-YuwkZdYhfHYWKTufL09wjxUCQhRl04zSqj0QqpAei6C1zHtT6tmKR-N1U2iNh_AB1_UF2m0YIC-Zt3u92v0a8ssaLBMzfsu-lsv3N4pbwxfJ1CJQHX1z9WaLP7_Y5Bm5yDfpULS4as5639RGhfydRVfEAJfvwrTB9QmCJ0GV7ZDmZlNSKwWozgHo0btgw3UVUp1py3xKef-V-a8NJx-401k7jgDW0N0D5C9AV6uXhCiAcpc7NYRxm4hWRgRDipC-SaQ_Mvbsn9vOZHrEiHc-rqWsMeDA_GfbpTqfZOXZY8xWFSIem0aa5apOACvPsAS_6UoVk2WImoqfjsNfnVC43svGDiwJG24SvHtesit7Kr17RaaINstWz8zoDX3ZCS5L4enA2zia-w5mZYz1Ej2L-_wgzeAdglBtUIM5qStnG_uTPHNCgr80JWo0PvUykI8NIzRl_eoMkJfUXo2wrmZrp-93gDA8KsL7NkzogkFHpm890R7PIo-x4HTQWRVS08pGacddFJWEJ4D_T29E2Cl2KbbpREuqlF6qApi0B99tsgABWfKE7b28r-Uuc2echWQbE"
self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: url, config: [.log(true), .compress, .path(""), .connectParams(["token": token])])
self.socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

Error log:

```
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://{DEV_URL}/?transport=polling&b64=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijc1M2Y5YmZkMjRiMzBmODA0N2JjMmQ1YzY4MzYxZjc2YzM5NjBhNTdmZjhmNWU5YmJmY2Q0NTdjZTIxNTY1ZjYwNTk5YTczZWM4NTJjNmMxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiNzUzZjliZmQyNGIzMGY4MDQ3YmMyZDVjNjgzNjFmNzZjMzk2MGE1N2ZmOGY1ZTliYmZjZDQ1N2NlMjE1NjVmNjA1OTlhNzNlYzg1MmM2YzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODQ2MjAzNDYsIm5iZiI6MTU4NDYyMDM0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTg1OTE2MzQ2LCJzdWIiOiIzMCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.Dhsn0vm1B7W_6sfHPgUox6qO3hYEnsvMQC_sGCNnviWNL_U45sUkT2W_dijjk2Px6ugyib6x9OcSqHB_bnKAWFdopZY7KU21uxxLy-p-f-YuwkZdYhfHYWKTufL09wjxUCQhRl04zSqj0QqpAei6C1zHtT6tmKR-N1U2iNh_AB1_UF2m0YIC-Zt3u92v0a8ssaLBMzfsu-lsv3N4pbwxfJ1CJQHX1z9WaLP7_Y5Bm5yDfpULS4as5639RGhfydRVfEAJfvwrTB9QmCJ0GV7ZDmZlNSKwWozgHo0btgw3UVUp1py3xKef-V-a8NJx-401k7jgDW0N0D5C9AV6uXhCiAcpc7NYRxm4hWRgRDipC-SaQ_Mvbsn9vOZHrEiHc-rqWsMeDA_GfbpTqfZOXZY8xWFSIem0aa5apOACvPsAS_6UoVk2WImoqfjsNfnVC43svGDiwJG24SvHtesit7Kr17RaaINstWz8zoDX3ZCS5L4enA2zia-w5mZYz1Ej2L-_wgzeAdglBtUIM5q
ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
ERROR SocketEngine: Error
ERROR SocketManager: Error
```

Did someone had similar issue or has solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with logger. After debugging the code, request had proper url while the logger trimmed the string for some reason.